# How do i change from unix to linux for connecting via c# (With telnet)?

Tags: c#, linux, telnet

I have code which has connection to a unix server: sample below:

**UnixTelnetConnection.Login(_server, _username, _password, FCART.Properties.Settings.Default.CleartoolPrompt.ToString());**

However, what needs to be different if its for linux? Does it have to be different?

Vidu

Comment: What do you mean by a unix server?  What operating system is it running?

Answer (score 3):

No, it should be fine. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using telnet, then a Linux machine and a Unix machine should respond identically.

However, on a Linux machine you are going to have GNU tools, while on other Unixes you are more likely to have BSD or SysV tools.  So, depending on what you are trying to do, there may be differences on the remote system.

What are you attempting to do with your Telnet connection?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, Telnet is its own protocol so there should be no difference on your end, no matter what OS the server is running. That said, you might have to pay attention to things like line endings, but that won't change from one POSIX system to the next. So just try to use the code you have and if it doesn't work come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I had to use the full name of it (server). eg: so11-1111.uuu.net as opposed to so11-1111. But it works now. So thats great :)